# assign variable to value of Dictionary Javascript

Tags: javascript, dictionary, variables, key

I am building a dictionary but I would like some of the values to contain variables. is there a way to pass a variable to the dictionary so I can assign a dot notation variable? the variables object will always have the same structure and the dictionary will be static and structured the same for each key value pair. essentially I want to pass the value from the dictionary to another function to handle the data.

main.js

```
import myDictionary from "myDictionary.js"

const variables ={
item:"Hello"
}
const data = myDictionary[key](variables)
console.log(data)
```

myDictionary.js

```
const myDictionary = {
key: variables.item
}
```

so the log should display hello. I know it willl be something straightforward but cant seem to figure it out.

as always any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Seems a bit like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is your ultimate goal, here - what do you want to achieve by transfering one dictionary to another function to handle automatically?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I must apologise as when I asked the question I wasn't fully clear on what I needed but after some experimentation and looking at my edge cases and after looking at Krzysztof's answer I had a thought and came up with something similar to this -

```
const dict = {
 key: (eventData) => {
          return [
            {
              module: 'company',
              entity: 'placement',
              variables: {
                placement_id: {
                  value: eventData.id,
                },
              },
            },
            {
              module: 'company',
              entity: 'placement',
              variables: {
                client_id: {
                  value: eventData.client.id,
                },
              },
            },
          ];
        },
      }
```

Then I'm getting the data like this -

```
const data = dict?.[key](eventData)

console.log(data)
```

I can then navigate or manipulate the data however I need.

thank you everyone who spent time to help me

Answer (score 1):

You should modify the dictionary so that it keeps actual callback functions instead. Only then it will be able to accept arguments.

```js
const myDictionary = {
  key: (variables) => variables.item
}

const variables = {
  item: "Hello"
}

const key = "key";
const data = myDictionary[key](variables)
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not possible. The myDictionary.js file has no idea whats inside you main file. The only thing you could do would be:

myDictionary.js

```
const myDictionary = {
    key: "item"
}
```

main.js

```
import myDictionary from "myDictionary.js";

const variables = {
    item: "Hello"
};

const data = variables[myDictionary["key"]];
console.log(data);
```

Also, even though JavaScript does not enforce semi-colons, they will save you a lot of headaches of some stupid rule that breaks the automatic inserter.